# Конвертировать pdf в картинку

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, discord.py

Я делаю бота для discord и мне нужно, чтобы имеющийся pdf файл (к примеру по пути pdffiles/test.pdf), каким-то образом "сканировался", и мне выдавало картинку(допустим по пути "img/test.png")

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[source:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064124/how-to-convert-multipage-pdf-to-list-of-image-objects-in-python)

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
images = convert_from_path('/path/to/my.pdf')
```